# discord.js (node:9852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: msg is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my source code:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
.then(deleted => message.channel.send(`Eu apaguei \`${deleted.size}´\ mensagens`))
msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
.catch(err => message.reply(`Alguma coisa deu errado... ${err}`));
```

`msg` is not defined, but when I try to define it, I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing one `.then()`:

```
message.channel
    .bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
    .then(deleted => message.channel.send(`Euapaguei \`${deleted.size}´\mensagens`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })))
    .catch(err => message.reply(`Alguma coisa deu errado... ${err}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your previous code, your `message` object is defined as `message`.
Therefore, instead of using the variable `msg` that doesn't exist, you should be using:

```
message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
```

Comment: I try that now, but doens't work, and now give the error in discord... DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Comment: `message` refers to the message the user sent. My guess is that the message returns unknown since you have already deleted it in the `bulkDelete()` method

Comment: Can explain better pls. @Elitezen

Comment: You have already deleted your message through your `bulkDelete()` method, meaning there's no need to delete it again, and the message object no longer exists as you have already deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

your message object is defined as message. Therefore, instead of using the variable msg that doesn't exist, you should be using:

```
message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
```